# How to double quote all fields in a text file?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, csv

I'm looking for a quick and efficient way to double quote all fields in tab delimited or comma separated text files.

Ideally, this would be a Perl one-liner that I can run from the command-line, but I'm open to any kind of solution.

Comment: And I'm open to any kind of effort; what have you tried?

Comment: Fair point. Sorry, I'm still new here. I've always done this just by using LibreOffice Calc, but I'm stuck with Microsoft Office at work, which can't easily do that.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
perl -MText::CSV -e'
  my $c = Text::CSV->new({always_quote => 1, binary => 1, eol => "\n"}) or die;
  $c->print(\*STDOUT, $_) while $_ = $c->getline(\*ARGV)' <<'END'
foo,bar, baz qux,quux
apple,"orange",spam, eggs
END
```

Output:

```
"foo","bar"," baz qux","quux"
"apple","orange","spam"," eggs"
```

The `always_quote` option is the important one here.

Answer (score 3):

If your file does not contain any double quoted strings containing the delimiter, you can use

```
perl -laF, -ne '$" = q(","); print qq("@F")'
```

Comment: +1 great. My answer should be `perl -F: -lane 'print join ",",map{qq{"$_"}}@F' < /etc/passwd` - but this is much nicer. ;)

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what would be the tab delimited version? I tried q(\t) and q("\t") but they don't produce the expected output.

Comment: @rent0n: To use a special character, you have to use `qq`, so `qq("\t")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{$0=q$0q;$1=$1}7' file
```

for example, comma sep:

```
kent $ echo "foo,bar,baz"|awk -F, -v OFS='","' -v q='"' '{$0=q$0q;$1=$1}7'
"foo","bar","baz"
```

tab sep would be similar.